# How to write output in a text file line by line while running a function using lapply?

Tags: r, apply, lapply

This is my function

```
Mc_bval<-function(filename){
  cat <- read.table(paste(cat_file, sep=""), header=TRUE)
  mag <- cat$Magnitude
  mag <- cat$Magnitude
  Mc_bootstrap <- numeric(nbsample)
  for(i in 1:nbsample) Mc_bootstrap[i] <- maxc(sample(mag, replace=TRUE),mbin)$Mc
  Mc_mean <- mean(Mc_bootstrap, na.rm=TRUE)
  Mc_sd <- sd(Mc_bootstrap, na.rm=TRUE)
  mag_b <- mag[mag>=Mc_mean]
  b <- b.guten(mag_b, Mc_mean)
  return(list(c(b=b),Mc=Mc_mean,Mc_sd=Mc_sd))
  #return(c(b=b,Mc))
}
```

Function is returning values,I want by reading each file name in the filelist.
I want to write output in one line for each file including the filename
This is the code i tried

```
filelist = list.files(pattern="*$.csv$")
outfile <- file("checkout.txt","w")
#apply(random_data, 2, checkfun, fileConn=outfile)

out = lapply(filelist,FUN = Mc_bval)
close(outfile)
```

Output file will be somewhat looks like this

```
cata_extract1.csv 1.46 0.25 4.15 0.33
cata_extract2.csv 1.44 0.35 4.25 0.23
cata_extract3.csv 1.4  0.25 4.25 0.24
cata_extract4.csv 1.34 0.85 4.25 0.23
```

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workable example based on what you have. I created an example function that accepts a `filename` and returns a list containing the length of the name and a random number.

After your `lapply`, you can use `writeLines` to output your filenames and list results (where your list results are converted to a character vector). In this case, you could use a second `paste` to concatenate the two vectors.

I hope this could be adapted for your use.

```
my_fun <- function(filename) {
  a = nchar(filename)
  b = sample(10,1)
  return(list(a, b))
}

filelist = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
outfile <- file("checkout.txt", "w")

out <- lapply(filelist, FUN = my_fun)

writeLines(paste(filelist, unlist(lapply(out, paste, collapse=" "))), outfile)

close(outfile)
```